# How to catch PHP "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: php, type-hinting

I am experimenting with PHP7 type hinting. 
Following code gives 'fatal error'. I tried few methods to no avail. 
It works Ok when i give int value. But if i give string it crashes. How can i catch type error without crashing my page. The code is:

```
<?php 

    class Book{
            public $price;
            public function price(int $price){
                if (is_numeric($price)){
                echo 'This is Number ' . $price;
                }else{
                    echo 'Please enter number';
                } 
            }
        }

    $book = new Book();
    $book->price('Hello');

?>
```

Comment: Hi guys, the main thing is, how can i catch such error without such inputs crashing my site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how type hinting works. If you tell PHP to expect an `int` value for a parameter and you pass it a value which is not an integer you will get a `TypeError` exception. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

You can implement your code slightly differently with a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $book->price('Hello');
}
catch (TypeError $e) {
    echo 'Please enter number';
}
```

In this case you can simplify the `price` function to:

```
public function price(int $price){
    echo 'This is Number ' . $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the function to accept `int` therefore you can't assign the string to it,
try this code.

> remove the `int` from the function params

```
class Book{
        public $price;
        public function price($price){
            if (is_numeric($price)){
            echo 'This is Number ' . $price;
            }else{
                echo 'Please enter number';
            } 
        }
    }

$book = new Book();
$book->price('hello');
```

Comment: No, dear Nasser. I want this input from users. Users might insert int or strings. If int is inserted i'd like to say 'Good', if INT is not inserted i'd like to display 'Please insert int' or like that.

Comment: @Aagii okay, according to your code if the function parameter is a string it will print the second echo, and if being an integer it will print the first echo.

Comment: @Aagii accually `is_numeric()` will check the input